# Using Lagrangian multipliers to find maximum and minimum values of $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1/2)^2+y^2+z^2}}$ for $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

We define $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1/2)^2+y^2+z^2}}$$ and find the maximum and minimum values of $f$ such that $$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$

Here is what I have so far:

$f(x)$ approaches a maximum as $1/f(x)$ approaches a minimum  and vice versa also $1/(f(x))^2$ does the same. So we define a new function $h(x)=1/(f(x))^2=(x+1/2)^2+y^2+z^2$ (side question: is it possible to shift $h(x)$ so it is simply $x^2+y^2+z^2$? or is this invalid?)

So we define the Lagrangian as $$L=((x+1/2)^2+y^2+z^2)+\lambda(x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$$

Then we get the following after taking partial derivatives:

$$L_x=2x+1+2\lambda x=0\\L_y=2y(1+\lambda)=0 \\ L_z=2z(1+\lambda)=0\\L_\lambda=x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0$$

But from here I am stuck, do we want to solve for $x,y,z,\lambda$? And how do we proceed from there if that is the case?

Comment: $$\dfrac{4(x^2+y^2+z^2)+4x+1}4=?$$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Expand $(x+1/2)^2$

Comment: $(x+1/2)^2=x^2+x+1/4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to solve the four equations simultaneously for $\lambda, x, y, z$. The second equation gives either $\lambda=-1$ or $y=0$. But if $\lambda=-1$ then the first equation becomes $1=0$. Therefore $y=0$, and similarly $z=0$ from the third equation. The fourth equation then gives $x^2=1$, so either $x=1$ or $x=-1$.

You can verify that $x=\pm1$ and $y=z=0$ are the values where $h(x,y,z)$ attains its max and min by using @lab bhattacharjee's hint: Given the constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, the function $h$ reduces to $x+\frac54$, which attains its max and min under that constraint when $x=\pm1$.

Comment: Okay I think I am following now just a few comments: 1. Could you instead define $(h(x)=x^2+y^2+z^2)$ and say this has approaches it's max/min as $(x+1/2)^2+y^2+z^2$ does or is that not true? 

2. Now we have shown the max and min occurs at $(\pm 1 ,0,0)$ would we just sub that into $f(x,y,z)$ to find max/min values $f(x,y,z)$ takes?

Comment: You can't use $g(x,y,z) :=x^2+y^2+z^2$ because that will have a different max/min from the original $h(x,y,z):=(x+\frac12)^2+y^2+z^2$. Notice that under the constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, the function $g$ is constant so its max and min occur at all choices of $x,y,z$ that satisfy the constraint. For your second question, the answer is yes!